# prettyPhoto additional close button

Tags: jquery, window, modal-dialog, prettyphoto

I have created some inline content that I am launching using the jQuery prettPhoto plugin. I want to add an extra close button within my content area but have no idea what is needed to do to make my button close the modal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

try this code in your close button's click event handler  
`window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.close();`